# Shockley-Queisser limit calculations

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electrical-engineering, solar-cells

I am working through the paper, [Detailed Balance Limit of Efficiency of p-n Junction Solar Cells by Shockley & Queisser](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1736034), for my own research with perovskite solar cells.

I am able to follow their logic but am having trouble with one of their calculations.

Given their equations (2.2) and $x_g\equiv \frac{h\nu_g}{k_B T_s}$,

$$Q_s \equiv Q(\nu_g,T_s)=\frac{2\pi}{c^2}\int^{\infty}_{\nu_g}\left[\exp{\left(\frac{h\nu}{k_B T_s}\right)}-1\right]^{-1}\nu^2d\nu \\ =\frac{2\pi}{c^2}\left(\frac{k_B T_s}{h}\right)^3 \int^{\infty}_{x_g}\frac{x^2}{e^x-1}dx$$

I can see that this is a straightforward change of variables from $\nu_g \rightarrow x_g$.
I am running into difficulty deriving a similar expression for $Q_c=Q(\nu_g,T_c)$ using another definition $x_c \equiv \frac{T_c}{T_s}$.

It's clear that $\frac{h\nu}{k_B T_c} = \frac{x_g}{x_c}$, but when I try to compute the value of the integral for $Q_c$

$$Q_c = \frac{2\pi}{c^2}\left(\frac{k_B T_c}{h}\right)^3 \int^{\infty}_{x_g/x_c}\frac{x^2}{e^x-1}dx$$

I don't get the answer that they get in their article. For an energy gap of $E_g=1.09 eV$ and $T_c=300\;K$ they get a value of $1700 \;cm^{-2}s^{-1}$ whereas I get $10.8 \;cm^{-2}s^{-1}$.

Is there some calculus step I am missing during the change of variables, I mean $\frac{T_c}{T_s}$ is just a constant, why would that affect anything? They never explicitly write out their equation for $Q_c$ so I'm wondering if anybody has encountered this before.